# Type casting error

Tags: apex, batch, class, global-methods, typecast

I am getting runtime type casting error with below code. Can someone please help?

Code:

```
global class batchCallUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Call_abv__c FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) {
         for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
         {
             a.Incidents_Count__c = [SELECT count() FROM Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__c WHERE (Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__c=:a.id
or Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Parent_Call_vod__c=:a.id) or (Call_detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__c=:a.id
or Call_detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Parent_Call_vod__c=:a.id)];            
         }
         update scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

> Error: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type
>   LIST to LIST

Class.IncidentListActionController1

Comment: Share your requirements and cases. Typecasting from one object to another is not possible or its something I'm unaware of till now .

Comment: Your query returns a list of `Incident_Transaction_abv__c` objects but your execute method takes a list `Call2_vod__c` objects.

Comment: BarCotter! Can you please suggest a way out here?

Comment: Mahmood! just that I have written . I have to take Call IDs from Incident Transaction and for those Calls calculate count and put it in Incidents_count__c field.

Comment: what is the relationship bw `Call2_vod__c` and `Incident_Transaction_abv__c`? is there any lookup / masterdetail? any other reference present? cant you just use rollup summary if it is a master/detail?

Comment: They dont have direct relation.

Comment: Then shouldn't you be querying your `Call2_vod__c` object in the start method? Why are you querying `Incident_Transaction_abv__c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahmood has it exactly, the reason for the runtime casting error is as follows

**Your start method**

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Call_abv__c FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

returns a list of `Incident_transaction_abv__c` SObjects

**but the execute method ...**

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) { ...
```

is expecting a list of a different SObject `Call2_vod__c`. As custom Sobjects don't support subclassing, SFDC, while invoking the execute() fails casting the list of `Incident_transaction_abv__c` to a list of `Call2_vod__c`

You need to rethink your batch class design objectives in light of your schema